# Use of Taxonomy Session Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise, taxonomy

I have gone through the following article regarding Taxonomy Session in Sharepoint

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee832800.aspx

But I couldn't get actual usage of taxonomy.I have assumed that taxonomy which is similar to store and retrieve data in Porperty bag.If my assumption is right or wrong could anyone help me to proivde why taxonomy and what is the need of taxonomy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the article you does not explain broad concepts behind Managed Metadata. In order to understand why it is necessary, I prefer to see a real world examples and its usage in SharePoint world.

To understand the concepts, you can refer to following articles:
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010-key.html

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/managed-metadata-addendum-why-metadata.html

And when you are ready to plan/design the managed metadata, you can refer to [Plan managed metadata (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530389.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Taxonomy is formally defined as the practice of classification according to natural relationships.

The taxonomy can be thought of as a system of classification or a hierarchy of terms that includes synonyms, translations and descriptions

A very good example, to understand the basic concept of taxonomy and its need, is looking at [biological classification *Kingdom-> Phylum-> Class-> Order-> Genus-> Species*](http://www.biologycorner.com/lesson-plans/evolution-taxonomy/taxonomy-notes/) we learned in high school biology.

In SharePoint 2010, Taxonomy Support is provided through the managed metadata infrastructure.
Managed metadata is a hierarchical collection of centrally managed terms that you can define, and then use as attributes for items in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Using Taxonomy documents can be tagged and then can be filtered based on the tags